# How to get twitter trends for certain cities

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/LocalTrendsMethods.html#getLocationTrends(int)

Is there a way to get twitter trends for citites like Reno, Nevada which is not part of the locations returned from http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/LocalTrendsMethods.html#getAvailableTrends()

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there not on the list, it's not possible using the twitter api. 
But you could try to filter on:

- the words "[Reno, Nevada, #Reno, #Nevada](https://twitter.com/#!/search/Reno%20OR%20Nevada%20OR%20#Reno%20OR%20#Nevada)".
- the location [using geocoding](https://twitter.com/#!/search/geocode:47.252877,-122.444291,15mi), but you'd have to know the latitude longitude of every city and you only get results from people who use the twitter locater.

Comment: 1. the words Reno, Nevada will only pull tweets with such references. its acutally hard to infer the trending information from those raw tweets. but if we use the call from twitter, it provides this information.

Comment: 2. We tried providing lat/long information for a city and tried it, but we were not certain if the trending information was appropriate (i.e. was it providing trending data based on the exact geo location or its surroundings also)

Comment: @Joe correct, that ecaxtly why twitter api does't include them on the availeble trends list. There not able to do this completely right. The above options are your only chance of doing it.